# How to test with collectiongroups on Firestore emulator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I would like to write JUnit tests that will use a local Firestore emulator.  How can I create a collectionGroup index on the emulator so I can test those parts of the code?

As far as I can see the gcloud firestore indexes command group will not access the emulator.

Comment: Are you referring to the emulator suite provided by the Firebase CLI?

Comment: the "gcloud beta emulators firestore start"
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/firestore/